# Reveal.js - Can't change theme

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I am using Reveal.js and I am trying to change the theme when a slide changes. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(){
  document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','css/theme/black.css');
});
```

I have also tried this on its own outside of the event listener, but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','css/theme/black.css');
```

Why isn't this changing the theme? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the DOM and the library are loaded before your script is executed. Try to move it before the `</html>` closing tag:

```
<script>
  Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(){
    document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','css/theme/white.css');
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. By the way, I am not using jQuery

Comment: I edited my answer. I added your script to the revealjs demo page and it works for me. Move your script at the bottom of your page and if it still not working, see if you have any error in console.

Comment: There was a naming error with the id of the original html tag. It is fixed now. Thanks